# c++ return type pointer declaration

Tags: c++, pointers, return-type

```
function: 
name: make_shape 
return: Shape* 
parameters: const string &shape_name; const vector &data
```

The class is `ShapeFactory`. This is what I have for this function definition:

```
 ShapeFactory::Shape* make_shape(const string &shape_name, const vector<double>&data)
```

I get an error that says:

> "ShapeFactory.cpp:17:15: error: ‘Shape’ in ‘class ShapeFactory’ does not name a type"

I know `Shape*` isn't a return type, but I don't know how to declare the pointer. Any suggestions?

Comment: Probably `Shape*  ShapeFactory::make_shape(const string &shape_name, const vector<double>&data)`1

Comment: `ShapeFactory::Shape` would only be correct if `Shape` is a nested class inside the `ShapeFactory` class.

Answer (score 1):

You've written `ShapeFactory::Shape* make_shape`, which the compiler thinks is the implementation of a function in `ShapeFactory` called `Shape*`. You need to have the return type before this, and the bit after the `::` is the function *name*. So, the correct code is:

```
 Shape* ShapeFactory::make_shape(const string 
 &shape_name, const vector<double>&data)
```

Comment: The compiler DOES NOT think `ShapeFactory::Shape* make_shape` is a function in `ShapeFactory` called `Shape*`.  It knows that `ShapeFactory::Shape*` is the return type and `make_shape` is the function name (of a standalone function, unless this function is declared inside the `ShapeFactory` class). The error message is specifically saying that `ShapeFactory` does not define a nested type named `Shape`, so `ShapeFactory::Shape*` is the wrong return type to use. Probably `Shape` is a standalone class, so the return type should be just `Shape*`, just like is written in the project requirement.